# What is the cardinality of the set of bounded functions φ:N→N

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I know that the set of functions f:N→N is uncountable but I'm unable to find an injective function from an uncountable set to the set of bounded functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

- $2^\mathbb{N}$ is the set of functions $\mathbb{N} \to \{0, 1\}$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!!

Answer (score 1):

As dtldarek has noted, there ae at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ such functions. But even if the functions weren't required to be bounded, there could be at most $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}\le (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ of them. Therefore, there are exactly $2^{\aleph_0}$ such functions. If you run through the proof of [the Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), you can even see how to construct an explicit bijection of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ with your set of functions.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing the explicit bijection, because I can't find the injection from $\{f:\mathbf N\to\mathbf N | f \text{ is bounded}\}$ to $\mathcal P(\mathbf N)$.  What subset does $n\mapsto n\pmod3$ map to, please?

Comment: @saulspatz To get injection from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ to $2^{\mathbb{N}}$, imagine $f$ as a sequence $f(0), f(1), f(2), \ldots$, write that sequence in unary with $1$'s and then put $0$'s as spaces. The same thing works for bounded too.

Comment: @dtldarek Very slick.  Thanks.